# How to extract and save the position information from nav_msgs to a text file

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a topic published named "cmd_local_waypoints" with two waypoints where the robot to go. I need to extract the X and Y position information from the topic and need to save it to a text file. The terminal response is shown below. You can see two position information available in the topic. I need to save it to a text file

Thanks in advance

```
header: 
  seq: 2219
  stamp: 
    secs: 17116
    nsecs: 995000000
  frame_id: ''
poses: []
---
header: 
  seq: 2220
  stamp: 
    secs: 17117
    nsecs:  14000000
  frame_id: base_link
poses: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 17117
        nsecs:  14000000
      frame_id: base_link
    pose: 
      position: 
        x: -2.32830643654e-05
        y: -2.32830643654e-05
        z: -2.32830643654e-05
      orientation: 
        x: 3.4668537268e-310
        y: 3.46685372677e-310
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 17117
        nsecs:  14000000
      frame_id: base_link
    pose: 
      position: 
        x: -2.32830643654e-05
        y: -2.32830643654e-05
        z: -2.32830643654e-05
      orientation: 
        x: 3.46686898944e-310
        y: 3.46688499512e-310
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319269/how-to-extract-and-save-the-position-information-from-nav_msgs-to-a-text-file/) by [manuelmelvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30611/manuelmelvin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-22**:
Please don't use an image to display text. Copy and paste the text from the image to your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same way you would in any other situation with a set of numbers you'd like to save to a file, how would you go about that? You could serialize the ROS message, but that doesn't sound like what you really want, you just want numbers. You can stream them to a file and save the file. Just access what you want from the message class and write to file in whatever way makes sense to you.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0